# In a Rails controller, is there a way to filter the params hash so that it only contains white-listed attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a controller's update action, I have:

```
entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])
```

There are some keys in `params[:entry]` that either correspond to non-accessible fields, or no field at all. If I don't have control over the values in `params[:entry]`, how can I filter it so that only accessible fields for the relevant model remain in it, presumably by accessing a list of the whitelisted attributes for the model? I know how to exclude/include keys from a hash, but I don't want to manually define the keys to include/exclude, because then I'd be duplicating the whitelist when it's already defined in the model.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its default in Rails 4, so you should use it :)

It also works in Rails 3: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Answer (score 2):

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except

except(*keys) public

Return a hash that includes everything but the given keys. This is useful for limiting a set of parameters to everything but a few known toggles:

```
@person.update_attributes(params[:person].except(:admin))
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do something like `@person.update_attributes(params[:person].only(Person.attr_accessible))` is that possible?

Comment: Found an answer, posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to the answer to the question of filtering a hash so it has only a selected set of keys, using rails slice method for Hash works along with the accessible attributes of the model.

```
@person.update_attributes(params[:person].only(*Person.attr_accessible[:default]‌​.to_a))
```

I think there's likely a neater way to do this, welcome suggestions.