# Rails 3.2.x: how to filter long parameters from getting logged using ActionController action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, actioncontroller

There are similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530215/in-a-rails-controller-is-there-a-way-to-filter-the-params-hash-so-that-it-only), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494999/filter-long-log-parameters-in-rails), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232554/how-to-filter-parameters-in-rails).

None help because the goal is to prevent logging of long parameters within a specific action instead of using `config.filter_parameters`. Also the answer must work for Rails 3.2.x while many answers are based on Rails 5.

One answer suggests calling `request.filtered_parameters` inside the controller method, but calling `request.filtered_parameters.delete :long_param` did not stop `:long_param` from getting logged.

Comment: What is it about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992561/712765) that does not work for you?

Comment: @OldPro thanks for helping! The goal is to filter an argument only within a specific action. Otherwise, we could use this answer.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, the easiest thing to do is to give that parameter a unique name so you can just filter all parameters of that name. The Rails Router gives you plenty of support for customizing parameter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`config.filter_parameters` takes a lambda function, so you can filter whatever you want. See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992561/712765) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992561/712765).

If you only want to filter long arguments for a specific action, well, you are making your life unnecessarily complicated. Either filter all long parameters, using your lambda to set a limit on parameter value length, or change the parameter key of the action you want to filter so that it is unique and and then just filter by that key.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with a little help from *Middleware filter*

Create new file `app/middleware/filter_long_params.rb`

```rb
class FilterLongParams

  def initialize(app, long_params = [])
    @app = app
    @long_params = long_params
  end

  def call(env)
    env["action_dispatch.parameter_filter"] += @long_params unless @long_params.empty?
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    [status, headers, response]
  end
end
```

Then add to your controller

```rb
class YourController
  use FilterLongParams, [:long_param_to_be_filtered], only: :update

end
```

First parameter of `use` is the name of Middleware class, second parameter should be the array of parameters you want to be filtered, and third may be the usual scope of controller actions.

If Rails 3.2 don't autoload `app/middleware` path, use `app/controllers` instead.